# Fastest way to upload a DataFrame to a table in MS SQL Server?

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I've been trying to upload a huge dataframe to table in SQL Server, the dataframe itself contains 1M+ rows with more than 70+ columns, the issue is that by trying multiple codes it takes 40 minutes or more to upload it. Is there a fastest way to do so? Here is a couple of codes that I've tried to use:

Using BCPandas takes 40 minutes:

```
from bcpandas import SqlCreds, to_sql
creds = SqlCreds(
  'server',
  'schema',
  'user',
  'password'
  )

to_sql(datadrameHuge,'table_test',creds,index = False, if_exists='append',schema='gcp')
```

Using SQLAlchemy takes more than an hour:

```
import urllib
import sqlalchemy
import pyodbc

server = 'servertest' 
database = 'dbtest' 
username = 'untest' 
password = 'passwordtest'  
driver = 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server'

params = 'DRIVER='+driver + ';SERVER='+server + ';PORT=1433;DATABASE=' + database + ';UID=' + username + ';PWD=' + password
db_params = urllib.parse.quote_plus(params)
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}".format(db_params))

pyodbc.drivers()



from sqlalchemy import event
@event.listens_for(engine, "before_cursor_execute")
def receive_before_cursor_execute(
       conn, cursor, statement, params, context, executemany
        ):
            if executemany:
                cursor.fast_executemany = True

dataframeHuge.to_sql('testtable', engine, index=False, if_exists="append", schema="dbo")
```

Is there a faster way to do this? Also does the connection speed affects the upload?

Comment: "does the connection speed affects the upload?" - Yes, obviously.

Comment: Is this Python code running local to server or remote?

Comment: @Parfait local to server

Comment: Wow! `bcp` cannot be that slow unless the package is having to do some other process like maybe cleaning. What are the data types of the 70 columns?

Comment: @Parfait Must of them are string, ints, floats and datetime types. It's also worth to say that some of the columns contains nulls on their totality (yeah I know is weird but the null columns are then populated with new info based on another project)

Comment: do you think if I change the all the dataframe to string and the table in sql server will make any impact?